# Selenium WebDriverJs commands

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am running a combination of Node.js + Mocha + Selenium Webdriverjs for the first time. I setup everything according to their documentation here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs, but I find it very difficult to actually find a list of all the commands available via the web driver. Is there a list of commands that are available to use when writing tests using Selenium webdriverjs?

For example how would I achieve the below java code using Javascript

```
new Wait("Couldn't find close button!") {
  boolean until() {
    return selenium.isElementPresent("button_Close");
  }
};
```

I know I can use `driver.wait` but it doesn't recognize the `until` command or the `isElementPresent`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I look here directly at the source file for docs. It's actually pretty good:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js

In answer to your question, you don't really want to wait in WebDriverJS, you want to get used to the deferred objects and promises api. I've just written a blog post about it here that should help you:

http://xolv.io/blog/2013/04/end-to-end-testing-for-web-apps-meteor

Comment: That blog link is now out of date. The correct link is: http://xolv.io/blog-posts/2013/04/end-to-end-testing-for-web-apps-meteor

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through the source code as well.  They have a compiled version of the API docs that is a bit easier to scan through here:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/module_selenium-webdriver.html

Unfortunately, there is no summary with just the method names.  You still have to scroll through the page.

In terms of how to wait:

```
webdriver = require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = ... // init your driver

driver.wait(webdriver.until...)
```

Answer (score 0):

@op, its best you use a chained statement. I use the until and isElementPresent command, and they work for production ready (CI/CD) train processes.
Tweaking your code thus should work

```
var isDisplayed = function(){
        driver.isElementPresent(by.id('button id')).then(function(isDisplayed){
            expect(isDisplayed).to.be.true
        });
    };
```