# Where is the documentation of Selenium Webdriver for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, documentation, code-documentation

I don't seem to find any, the only one I always find is this one:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

But it is more a guide. Not a documentation of all functions. It lacks for example the documentation for `Webdriver.Window`, or something like `getWindowHandles()`

Comment: I'm having the same problem and there is almost no proper examples out there as gar as I know. Please share, if you found something!

Comment: This question has a large view count and serves a purpose - this piece of documentation is rather hidden

Answer (score 16):

I always need to re-find this, so I might as well capture it here

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/

Comment: I was looking for this forever, ridiculous that they hide it like that. +1!

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found is to look at the source code itself at: 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js

And then there is this automatically generated documentation: 
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver.html

I found it in these answers:

[Selenium WebDriverJs commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506037/selenium-webdriverjs-commands) 
[WebDriver (Selenium 2) API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644868/webdriver-selenium-2-api-documentation?rq=1)